# Hosting Asp.Net Core 2 on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express

My application works good when started in Release/Debug mode via Visual Studio in both ApplicationName and IISExpress.

But once deployed to IIS and started, I cannot access home page (home controller) and also have Navigation bar issues and JQuery issues. I have published the app in both Debug/Release mode to no avail.

My question mainly is how can I fix this? The app should run the same way it runs locally on iisexpress right? Even if a file was missing (as in debug/release env), Home controller should be access as is right?

Will greatly appreciate any help and waiting to post more information and logs based on comments.

Edit 1 (to include Startup.cs):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MTAClassLib.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace MTALib
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var RoleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                UserRoleSeed.Seed(RoleManager).Wait();
            }
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .Build();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same issue with having ASP.Net Core 2 run on IIS. I had to

1. install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle. This can be downloaded https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting if you haven't done so.
2. Run IISReset in Command line window after installing Hosting Bundle
3. Ensure that your project.cs BuildWebHost method looks as follows

   ```
   public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseKestrel()
           .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .UseIISIntegration()
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .Build();}
   ```
4. I didn't have to change application pool to .NET CLR version to "No Managed Code". It remained as ".Net CLR Version v4.0.30319"
5. Edit the web.config and change stdoutLogEnabled to true.
6. Create logs folder manually in the published folder.

This solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting of ASP.NET Core 2.0 is a little different from hosting in ASP.NET.

You need to [Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

Also, make sure your **Application Pool** >> **.NET CLR version** should be **No Managed Code**

For more details refer to [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

[image]

Comment: That's what I have done. But I can't visit my Home page (index action in home controller) and having issues with implementing windows authentication even with Windows Authentication Enabled.

Comment: Did you check [Configure Windows authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)? Also try to share your `Startup.cs` content

Answer (score 0):

Installing "dotnet-hosting-2.1.2-win.exe" and resetting IIS has resolved the problem for me.